# Remote usage and DI for DbContext in EF Core (3.0)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to isolate database "core" as a service on isolate machine and get access through the TCP/IP or other connection layer from other services which are needed data from database (remote database connection).
In the database service I want to create in-memory dbcontext which subsitutes database dbcontext requests by DI.

Could someone explain me the best and right way to do this? Possible, there are some projects on github or this functionality could be found in the EF Core (3.0) "out of the box"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rest of your question was understandable (though broad), but you lost me with:

> In the database service I want to create in-memory dbcontext which subsitutes database dbcontext requests by DI.

You can certainly create an HTTP service to use for persistence instead of using `DbContext` directly. That's basically what microservices are. However, you will need to interact with that service via a *client*. In the case of an HTTP service, or an API as it's more commonly referred, that client would be `HttpClient`. It sounds like you want to somehow still use `DbContext`, but have it interact with this service under the hood. That is not possible.

As far as "out of the box" goes. There's not really anything, as each data source and therefore microservice, is different. About the closest you can get is using OData or GraphQL. Both will require some degree of configuration, so they're still not "out of the box", but either will then allow you to issue query-like requests against an endpoint, meaning you won't necessarily need to design tons of different endpoints to handle different types of queries or operations.

Comment: "In the database service I want to create in-memory dbcontext which subsitutes database dbcontext requests by DI" - I mean that I want to use the same DbContext derived class for 2 instanses, one stores data in memory database, other stores data in database on disk from first database by sheduled task. In-memory database is a cache with custom logic I want to describe by myself.

Comment: So, what's the best way to realize client - through MVC Controller or gRPC?

Comment: There is no "best" way. It's whatever works best for you, your team, your organization, and your app. Nobody can make that call for you. Research the various methods and make a determination.

Comment: Well, like I said, it's similar in theory to microservices architecture, so that's basically your design pattern, but there's literally millions of ways that could be done with any number of combinations of backend storage, providers, frameworks, libraries, protocols, network components, etc.